# Using date function in bash to parse year and month

Tags: linux, bash

I have the below code, where I am trying to parse a date with only the year and month given;

```
input_date="2023-08"

formatted_date=$(date -d "$input_date-01" +%Y-%m)

echo "Year: $(date -d "$formatted_date" +%Y)"

echo "Month: $(date -d "$formatted_date" +%m)"
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
Year: 2023

Month: 08
```

But instead it simply returns an error of date: invalid date '2023-08'

I know i can add a "-01" day but for my use case I want the user to be able to enter YYYY-MM or YYYY-MM-DD and parse this using the date function.

The reason I want the YYYY-MM format is so i can use the wildcard pattern when searching

Any way I can do this easily in bash?

Comment: You didn't inspect `formatted_date`?

Comment: Better test your broken scripts on https://shellcheck.net before asking help here

Comment: What do you, sorry?

formatted_date remains empty as the command did not work

Comment: Your edit made it more broken than it was when I answered.  I rolled it back so the answer addresses it correctly.

Comment: not sure what the need for rudeness is, but my point is I want to my able to parse it simply as YYYY-MM format. I'd rather not want to add the extra "01" for the day because i want to search files using the wildcard pattern such as: ls "filename-2023-08*"

Comment: Check which `date` you're using.  If `date --version` doesn't tell you it's from GNU coreutils, I wouldn't expect `-d` to work.

Comment: Did you think I was being rude?  I certainly didn't mean to be, and I'm sorry if you thought I was.  Why is adding `-01` a problem inside your code?  You still have `$input_date` if you need the version with only the year and month.

Comment: I guess StillAyo rather means my wording "mindlessly", though I think it objectively describes not using one's mind here.

Comment: Have you considered reading the `info` pages for [date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html)? A date without a day is never valid.

Answer (score 1):

`formatted_date` looks just like the input date (missing the day number).

You'll want to format it as `%F` (or perhaps as `@%s` for full fidelity).

Quick demo:

```bash
input_date="2023-08"

formatted_date=$(date -d "$input_date-01" +%F)

date -d "$formatted_date" +"Year: %Y"
date -d "$formatted_date" +"Month: %m"
```

or

```bash
input_date="2023-08"

formatted_date=$(date -d "$input_date-01" +@%s)

date -d "$formatted_date" +"Year: %Y"
date -d "$formatted_date" +"Month: %m"
```

Both of these are plain POSIX shell, so will work in Bash or any other conforming shell.

Comment: I've edited my original post so its just "$input_date".

The issue is formatted_date remains empty as parsing with the date function did not work

Comment: I've rolled back that edit, because it broke the part of the code that was working.

Comment: Is it possible to do without appending the "01"?

Comment: I don't think so.  Except that you could add a different day number instead (which would eliminate some risks if you're working with multiple time-zones).  But given that including a day number is so simple, why wouldn't you?